# If statement in awk works not as predicted

Tags: shell, unix, awk

My second column values are starting from 0 to 2000, and variable $a is set to be 13. If statement in awk does not work as it supposed to it... it prints all values. Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=- read a b <<< "$1"
echo $a # value is displayed as 13
echo $b # value is displayed as 20... for now it does not matter
sort -r -k 2,2 $2 | awk '{if ($2 > $a) print $2}'  # if statement should check which of a second column values are greater than 13, and print them
```

Everything is okay when I compare my second column like this (putting 13 instead of $a):

```
 sort -r -k 2,2 $2 | awk '{if ($2 > 13) print $2}'
```

So my thought is that I put $a in If statement wrong

Comment: Maybe a type problem. What do you get you when convert to numbers explicity with `if (($2+0) > ($a+0))...` ? Can you provide some use/in/output examples ?

Comment: awk is not shell. see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because shell variables will not get expanded withing single quotes.

awk has a handy mechanism to set *awk* variables:

```
awk -v value="$a" '{if ($2 > value) print $2}'
```

which can be written more "awkishly" as

```
awk -v value="$a" '$2 > value {print $2}'
```

Comment: How to assign one more variable to awk? Something like this: awk -v var="$a",var2="$b" '{if ($2 > var $$ $2 < var2) print $2}'

Comment: use separate -v options: `awk -v v1="$a" -v v2="$b" 'v1 < $2 && $2 < v2 {print $2}'` -- note `&&` is logical-and, not `$$`

Comment: Oh my attention was on the other problem. Thanks for help it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk  -v var="$a" '{if ($2 > var)print $2}'
```

should do it. You can't access the shell variables directly in awk. You need to use the `-v` option to store shell variables to awk variables.

**Note:** Awk variables do not require a preceding `$` as in bash, a notable exception is accessing columns/fields (say $1,$2 etc).

Comment: wrt `$1`, `$2`, etc. - don't think of `1` and `2` as variables which need a `$` in front of them - instead, if you need to draw a correlation, think of `$` as the name of an array with indices `1` and `2` as that has more similarities (e.g. `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print array[i]` vs `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i`)